Print all pages to pdf excluding the last page
I'm attempting to create VBA code to print all pages of a document to a PDF file, excluding the last page. However, the current code I have prints the entire document, including the last page. How can I modify the existing code to print the entire document while excluding the last page?
Sub PrintAllPagesExceptLastToPDF()
    Dim LastPage As Long
    Dim SecondLastPage As Long
    Dim PDFFileName As String
    
    ' Get the total number of pages in the document
    LastPage = ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
    
    ' Extract the existing file name without extension
    PDFFileName = Left(ActiveDocument.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".") - 1)
    
    ' Determine the second-to-last page
    SecondLastPage = LastPage - 1
    
    ' Print all pages except the last one to PDF
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat outputFileName:=PDFFileName & ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, From:=1, To:=SecondLastPage, OpenAfterExport:=False
End Sub

